# iterate over a set of dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

Let's say I have a set of dataframes: `df1, df2, d3, df4`. I want to apply some sort of behaviour over each of these dataframes. Rather than copying the code repeatedly, I want to do this through some sort of for loop. For example, let's say I want to take the df and re assign it so that the first column is row names. The normal way I'd do this is:

```
df1_b <- df1[,-1]
rownames(df1_b) <- df1[,1]
```

How would I go about doing this to all four dataframes that I have. I imagine I'd need to somehow make group the dataframes into a single `set` and then do something like

```
for (i in set) {
  i+"_b" <- i[,-1]
  rownames(i_b) <- i[,1]
}
```

I tried to do this with a cbind:

```
df_set <- c(df1, df2, df3, df4)
for (i in df_set) {
  i+"_b" <- i[,-1]
  rownames(i_b) <- i[,1]
}
```

But of course that didn't work (I'm pretty sure R does not do string concatenation like this).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're correct that R doesn't do concatenation that way, but you can use `paste(i, "b", sep = "_")`. But you'd be well off making a list of data frames and iterating over them with something like `lapply` or `purrr::map`. Lots of SO posts already on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get the values of the multiple objects into a `list` and then do  the processing in the `list` by looping over the `list` with `lapply`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:4)), function(x) {
               row.names(x) <- x[,1]
                x[,-1]
    })
```

If we want to change the original objects (not recommended)

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or another option is `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$")) %>%
     map(~ .x %>%
               column_to_rownames(names(.)[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually love the tidyverse solution. With it, do you have to use map vs. a for loop in R? Not that it matters, I suppose.

Comment: @BOBjwjwj3j3j  `for` loop also works.  I don't like to create multiple objects, so  would like to keep it in a `list`

Comment: Fantastoc. One final question: in this case the `columns_to_rownames` solution returns "Can't find column `1` in `.data`.". I think this is because the first cell of the first column is a character string (and its different between each df). Is there a way to specify the thing at index [,1]?

Comment: @BOBjwjwj3j3j  sorry, it would be `column_to_rownames(names(.)[1])`

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a function this way for example:

```
# getting some dummy data
df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- mtcars
df3 <- mtcars
df4 <- mtcars

lst <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

# example of applying the function row.names to the data
Map(row.names, lst)
```